# using the clipboard in native c++ metro app

Tags: c++, windows, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, wrl

I'm looking for the interfaces to allow me to access the clipboard in native c++ metro app - similar to DataTransfer::Clipboard::SetContent in C#.

can someone please refer me to those interfaces and how can it be done using the WRL library?

Comment: Is this what you mean? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.clipboard.setcontent?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1

Comment: Do you need WRL, or can you use C++/CX?

Answer (score 1):

In WRL, you need to get the IClipboardStatics interface which contains the SetContent method.

```
#include <Windows.Foundation.h>
#include <Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.h>
#include <wrl\wrappers\corewrappers.h>
#include <wrl\client.h>

using namespace ABI::Windows::Foundation;
using namespace Microsoft::WRL;
using namespace Microsoft::WRL::Wrappers;
using namespace ABI::Windows::ApplicationModel::DataTransfer;

    // Initialize the Windows Runtime.
    RoInitializeWrapper initialize(RO_INIT_MULTITHREADED);

    if (FAILED(initialize))
    {
        cout << "Failed to initialize";
    }

    ComPtr<IClipboardStatics> clipboard;

    HRESULT hr = GetActivationFactory(HStringReference(RuntimeClass_Windows_ApplicationModel_DataTransfer_Clipboard).Get(), &clipboard);

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        cout << "failed to create a runtime instance";

        return 0;
    }

    ComPtr<IDataPackage> datapackage;

    // create a package and set the data
    // ...

    clipboard->SetContent(datapackage.Get());
```

Comment: thanks! is there any documentation for those interfaces? where did you find?

Comment: No document, I found it in the c++ header file Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.h

Comment: The above GetActivationFactory fails with the following error: "Activating a single-threaded class from MTA is not supported". only when I call RoInitialize with RO_INIT_SINGLETHREADED it works. but it doesn't make sense - I attached a debugger to a few Windows store apps to see all their calls to RoInitialize and it's always with RO_INIT_MULTITHREADED. so how they manage to perform copy/paste, why the underlying implementation in the Windows Runtime succeeds where I fail?